# How do I print from my EDA/stats pipeline in a function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, printing, instance

This is my problem: Attempting to print from a def (for control purposes and to see that calculations are delivering expected results), I encounter issues on getting the actual printed result. I create an instance of a particular object, but the code runs without presenting print result. def_EDA.py is just a playground .py file.

Below code is adapted from a tutorial, adding # to some lines I do not want to work with here and now.

This is what I did to e.g. identify outliers as part of my data analysis:

```
from myfile import df1, df2, df3

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import math

cont_group = ['MyCount','User Name'] # continuous variables

def UVA_outlier(df1, MyCount, include_outlier=True):
    '''
    Univariate_Analysis_outlier:
    takes a group of variables (INTEGER and FLOAT) and plot/print boplot and descriptives\n
    Runs a loop: calculate all the descriptives of i(th) variable and plot/print it \n\n

    data : dataframe from which to plot from\n
    var_group : {list} type Group of Continuous variables\n
    include_outlier : {bool} whether to include outliers or not, default = True\n
    '''

    size = len(df2)
    plt.figure(figsize=(7 * size, 4), dpi=100)

    # looping for each variable
    for j, i in enumerate(MyCount):

        # calculating descriptives of variable
        quant25 = df1[i].quantile(0.25)
        quant75 = df1[i].quantile(0.75)
        IQR = quant75 - quant25
        med = df1[i].median()
        whis_low = med - (1.5 * IQR)
        whis_high = med + (1.5 * IQR)
        print(quant25) # not delivering print
        print(quant75) # same issue
        print(IQR) # same issue
        print(med) # same issue
        print(whis_low) # same issue
        print(whis_high) # same issue

        # Calculating Number of Outliers
        outlier_high = len(df1[i][df1[i] > whis_high])
        outlier_low = len(df1[i][df1[i] < whis_low])

        if include_outlier == True:
            print(include_outlier)
            # Plotting the variable with every information
            # plt.subplot(1, size, j + 1)
            # sns.boxplot(df1[i], orient="v")
            # plt.ylabel('{}'.format(i))
            # plt.title(
            #     'With Outliers\nIQR = {}; Median = {} \n 2nd,3rd  quartile = {};\n Outlier (low/high) = {} \n'.format(
            #         round(IQR, 2),
            #        round(med, 2),
            #        (round(quant25, 2), round(quant75, 2)),
            #        (outlier_low, outlier_high)
            #     ))

        else:
            # replacing outliers with max/min whisker
            data2 = df1['MyCount'][:]
            data2[i][data2[i] > whis_high] = whis_high + 1
            data2[i][data2[i] < whis_low] = whis_low - 1

            # plotting without outliers
            # plt.subplot(1, size, j + 1)
            # sns.boxplot(data2[i], orient="v")
            # plt.ylabel('{}'.format(i))
            # plt.title(
            #    'Without Outliers\nIQR = {}; Median = {} \n 2nd,3rd  quartile = {};\n Outlier (low/high) = {} \n'.format(
            #        round(IQR, 2),
            #        round(med, 2),
            #        (round(quant25, 2), round(quant75, 2)),
            #        (outlier_low, outlier_high)
            #   ))

test = UVA_outlier(df1, MyCount=df1['MyCount'])

print(test.quant25)  # trying to print creating an instance of the UVA_outlier def
print(test.quant75)  # trying to print creating an instance of the UVA_outlier def
```

This is what I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../def_EDA.py", line 83, in <module>
    test = UVA_outlier()
TypeError: UVA_outlier() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'df1' and 'MyCount'
```

I did try to apply the required positional argument as shown, ending up with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2891, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 2

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../def_EDA.py", line 83, in <module>
    test = UVA_outlier(df1, MyCount=df1['MyCount'])
  File "C:/.../def_EDA.py", line 34, in UVA_outlier
quant25 = df1[i].quantile(0.25)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 2
```

Once again, I did get heavily inspired by the tutorial I followed, but initially I would expect some ability to print, just to get to know that e.g. quant25, quant75, etc would tell me that I am on the path to identify outliers in my data. Any help is appreciated. Happy New Year! BR Hubsandspokes

Comment: I don't understand what all the text and code has to do with printing. You seem to have several other problems, but they don't seem to be related to using the `print` function.

Comment: I regret all the text. Maybe, you can then point to my actual issue.

Comment: Apparently `df1` has no index (or key, I'm not that familiar with Pandas) 2.

Comment: OK, thx - what other issues do you see?